# Authentication Error while retrieving html code c#

Tags: c#, web-services, url, httpclient

I am trying to retrieve the source code of a site by using the built in webclient class. I can not find a work around for the problem I am getting:

error 407: proxy authentication Required

When written in java, it works fine but I am re-writing it in C# and it happens everytime. The url is not the issue, I have debugged it to the point before it crashes and tested the url it is using.

Here is the code:

```
private String getUrlSource(String url)
{

  using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
  {
      string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
      return htmlCode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by incorrectly configured [Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.proxy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property. Also check out related [Automatic Proxy Detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fze2ytx2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article.

Potential fix below, but you'd probably need to find correct proxy configuration in your case.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient {Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy })
```

Note that proxy configuration is per user account, so if code runs from under service's account it may not have correct proxy configured at all - you'd need to manually set correct proxy in code in corresponding configuration file.